# Listner for JRadioButtonMenuItem to get the event on disposal

Tags: java, swing, jmenuitem

I have a class extending JRadioButtonMenuItem. Is there a way that I can capture an event when the instance of my class is getting disposed from the UI. I am not sure which listener to have to capture this event.

To put it more clearly, I have a set of `JRadioButtonMenuItem` instance(actually instance of a class that extends `JRadioButtonMenuItem`), as per the implementation that i have the instance is added as listener to one of my class,say `EventSourceEx` and listening. This will be added as a listener when the instance of `JRadioButtonMenuItem`  is getting created.

So when the *JMenu* containing the menu item instance mentioned above,disappears I want to remove the `JRadioButtonMenuItem` from `EventSourceEx`instance. So my idea is if there is an even that I can capture from the `JRadioButtonMenuItem` or the `JMenu`, I'll be notified that the menu/Menuitem is getting disposed so that I'll remove the instance from the `EventSourceEx`.
Does `JMenu` or `JRadioButtonMenuItem` has any mechanism to notify an even when it dissapears.

Comment: @Kleopatra: I am having a set of components that is displaying in the JRadioButtonMenuItem instance. Those components will be added as listners to one of my class for an app specific event. I want to remove those listeners when the menu is disposed.

Comment: sorry, don't understand your setup (f.i. a menuItem isn't meant to act as a container, so don't know how components could be displaying _in_ it. Also components _are not_ listeners, so could not be added/removed to anything) Best to show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing/trying to achieve and explain with it why you need to be notified on _dispose_

Comment: @Kleopatra:I have edited the question description. It will be clear now I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add property changed listener to your JMenuItem Component.

Override propertyChange() method

public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent theEvt)

{

if ( !isShowing() && "ancestor".equalsIgnoreCase(theEvt.getPropertyName()) &&   theEvt.getNewValue() == null)

```
 {

 // Youcan remove your listener

 }
```

}

try this one... and let me know

Comment: wow... I added the instance of the JMenuItem as a listener to itself and that fixed the issue. Thanks Sudheesh..:)

Comment: Not Sudheesh dude this Ramesh

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to capture this event.  Focus on capturing the event that you care about that is disposing the container that the button is on.  For example if the button is on a frame that is getting closed then add a `WindowListener`.  If the button is removed programatically and re-validated add a call into that code to the logic that you need to be executed.